# How can I set the input object on an Angucomplete-Alt dropdown from my scope?

Tags: angularjs

I have two autocomplete dropdowns that can be searched on independently.  But I also have the requirement that when one is selected, the other should auto-fill.  From what I see I have two options, set the `selected-object` but this is a one-way binding, and `initial-value` which lets me set the object but only on load.

So how can I achieve this dynamically.  I imagine it to be a pretty common use case, there should be a way.  This project is my first foray into AngularJS, so I'm hoping I just missed something simple.

Comment: I have the same question, did you ever find out how to do this?

Comment: @Sehael Never did, ended up switching to bootstrap-ui typeahead, was able to achieve the same functionality as angucomplete with it.  It uses ng-model with two-way binding so had no problems setting the input object whenever I pleased.